# I want to open html page as popup window in my html page when i press button

Tags: html

please send any reference

Comment: When u typed this question, Stack overflow showed u some suggestion!  did u mind opening any of them?

Comment: Hey I am new to programing, don't think badly on me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com');">Open popup</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with following code, but popup window isn't opened 
 
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Scan" language="javascript" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com';)"/></td>

Comment: @Drop, is your browser blocking popups? and change `google.com` to `http://www.google.com` and see what happens.

Comment: Still popup window isn't opened with www.google.com

Comment: `window.open('google.com';)` is your problem. Don't put the `;` **inside** the bracket, rather do this `window.open('http://www.google.com');`.

Comment: Cool, if it helped you, accept the solution (click on the big tick underneath the voting system) and give Darin the score.